# Find a file and then use its name as a variable Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

How do I look for a file and assign file name to a variable?

Example:
Let's say I am looking for a file in below location.  File name constantly changes and only way to pick up the right file is by looking for today's date in file name string:

```
X:\VoyagerBackups\PickupLocation\tsiuiolou_live_Full_PCV048DB42_201812140000.Lts.bak
```

Here's what I have so far in my .bat file.  Execution works as expected if I hard-code file name:

```
echo on
Rem Determine date
Set mm1=%date:~4,2%
Set dd1=%date:~7,2%
Set yyyy1=%date:~10,4%

Set rundate1=%yyyy1%%mm1%%dd1%

Set executefile1=tsiuiolou_live_Full_PCV048DB42_%rundate1%0000.Lts.bak
set downloadfile=tsiuiolou_live_Full_PCV048DB42_%rundate1%0000.bak

extractor64.exe -F %executefile1% -E %downloadfile%

move %executefile1% X:\VoyagerBackups\BackupFiles
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the locale/user settings dependant %date% variable.

Use either `wmic` or PowerShell instead, they both have more stable methods.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\14\SO_53787816.cmd
@Echo off

for /f "usebackq" %%A in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')"
`) Do Set "Today1=%%A"
Echo PowerShell today:%Today1%

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) do Set "Today2=%%A"
Set "Today2=%Today2:~0,8%"
Echo       wmic today:%Today2%

Set "Base=X:\VoyagerBackups\PickupLocation\"
PushD "%Base%" || (Echo can't find base:%Base%&Pause&Goto :Eof)

For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B "*%Today1%*" ') Do (
    Echo found file:%%~fA
)
PopD
```

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by wmic or PowerShell being more stable than CP/batch file?

Comment: The first two `for` commands in my answer demonstrate the use of powershell and wmic on how to obtain the date in `yyyyMMdd` format => `%Today1%`,`%Today2%`. The last for shows how to get a file with this date in the name.